# How to split only on empty line

Tags: powershell, split, paragraph

Let's say I have a `.txt` file like this:

```
abc:def ghi:jkl
xyz-www fff

grz,ggg,ewqe
dgokd fddfs

ssokpwe_klk
```

What I would like is to read that into PowerShell, and split it by every empty line into objects, so in the end i should have three objects in an array like this:

```
# Object 1
abc:def ghi:jkl
xyz-www fff
#Object 2
grz,ggg,ewqe
dgokd fddfs
#Object3
ssokpwe_klk
```

I tried the following stuff:

Reading in the file in these three ways:

```
Get-Content "D:\a.txt"
Get-Content "D:\a.txt" -Raw
Get-Content "D:\a.txt" | Out-String
```

and to split the following ways:

```
.split("\n{2,}")
.split(([System.Environment]::NewLine + [System.Environment]::NewLine))
.split("\r\n\r\n")
```

However, it always didn't only split on the blank white line, but splitted inside the objects as well.

How can I really only split on empty lines, and how do I need to read in my content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following using `-split` operator:

```
(Get-Content a.txt -Raw) -split '(?:\r?\n){2,}'
```

**Explanation:**

Using `-Raw` switch reads the file as one string. `(?:)` is a non-capturing group so that the matched newline characters are removed upon splitting. The blank line will likely only be newline characters (CR matched by `\r` and/or LF matched by `\n`). `\r?` will still match if there is no CR character in your file. `{2,}` matches two or more of the previous match.

Using the `.Split()` method, you can't use regex syntax as it does not interpret it. `Split(Params char[] separator)` overload doesn't recognize consecutive character sequences. It uses each input string as an array of characters. It will then apply a split for each character that matches. So `'hithereagain'.Split('there')` has the same result as `'hithereagain'.Split('eerth')`.

Comment: Nicely done; if you also want to avoid a trailing newline in the last output array element (which will be there if the input file ends in one), you can use `(Get-Content -Raw a.txt) -split '(?:\r?\n){2,}|\r?\n\z' -ne ''`. While this also eliminates 2 or more _leading_ empty lines from the output array (which would otherwise become an empty-string element), that is probably desirable too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = Get-Content -Path "file.txt"
$objects = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[System.String]
$lines = [System.String]::Empty
foreach ($line in $file) {  
    if ([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($line)) {
        if (![System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lines)) {
            $objects.Add($lines)
        }
        $lines = [System.String]::Empty
    }
    else {
        if ([System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lines)) {
            $lines = $line
        }
        else {
            $lines = "$lines$([System.Environment]::NewLine)$line"
        }
    }
}
if (![System.String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lines)) {
    $objects.Add($lines)
}

#Printing all objects
$n = 1
foreach ($value in $objects) {
    Write-Host "█ Object $($n):"
    Write-Host $value
    Write-Host
    $n += 1
}
```

**Output**

```
█ Object 1:
abc:def ghi:jkl
xyz-www fff

█ Object 2:
grz,ggg,ewqe
dgokd fddfs

█ Object 3:
ssokpwe_klk
```

**Tested with following input**

---

```
"abc:def ghi:jkl
xyz-www fff

grz,ggg,ewqe
dgokd fddfs

ssokpwe_klk"
```

---

```
"abc:def ghi:jkl
xyz-www fff

grz,ggg,ewqe
dgokd fddfs



ssokpwe_klk"
```

---

```
"abc:def ghi:jkl
xyz-www fff

grz,ggg,ewqe
dgokd fddfs

ssokpwe_klk

"
```

Comment: thanks but this is not at all what I would need. this is just outputting all the lines, however i need to split at the blank line and have it as an own object, not manipulated